# Yii2 HttpBearerAuth, как возвращать свой текст ошибки?

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет, у меня есть данный код:

```php
<?php

$behaviors = parent::behaviors();

$behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
    'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
    'formats' => [
        'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON
    ]
];

$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
    'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className()
];

return $behaviors;
```

Все отлично работает. Но я бы хотел возврашать кастомное сообщение об ошибке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы я мог сам возвращать свое сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо создать свой класс аутентификации, который унаследовать от HttpBearerAuth. В своем классе переопределить метод handleFailure($response), который будет возвращать необходимое сообщение.

```
class Auth extends HttpBearerAuth
{
    public function handleFailure($response)
    {
        throw new HttpException('My custom message.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Но как мне убрать type из data?я не хочу чтобы был виден путь

Comment: type не будет отображаться, когда фреймворк в прод режиме.

Comment: Спасибо большое!